# Display Custom CMS Fields in Magento 2 Template

Tags: magento2, template, cms-pages

I'm can't seem to find any documentation on how to get custom CMS fields in a PHTML template in Magento2. The following snippet did it in Magento2:

```
Mage::getBlockSingleton('cms/page')->getPage()->getContentCustom()
```

What is the Magento 2 equivalent?

(the custom fields have already been added to the admin page and are writing to the database.